# Is it possible to detect the origin of a 302 redirect?

Tags: http, http-headers

Let's say that I have a webserver hosted a url `fakeurl.net` and there is another webserver hosted at `alsofake.com` which sends a 302 response redirecting to `fakeurl.net`. I have been intercepting and analyzing the requests send in such a situation with wireshark, but I cannot see any way for `fakeurl.net` to know that the user was redirected by `alsofake.com`. Maybe I am missing something though.

Is it possible to detect (the origin of) a 302 redirect to your website?

*Note that I know there are many different ways of achieving the same thing with different HTTP codes and headers in which it is easy to detect the origin of a redirect, I'm just wondering if it is possible for a 302 request specifically.*

Comment: A normal browser should set the "Referer" header.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart That's what I thought, but neither Chrome nor Firefox sets it for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to detect it since a 302 acts like a direct visit to `fakeurl.net`.

Using `Referer` does not make sense because direct visits to `fakeurl.net` normally don't have `Referer`.

Comment: This matches my experience, I set up a lab scenario and watched the packet.s with Wireshark. There is no possible/consistent way of detecting a 302..